# Endless loop crashing VShost

Tags: c#, sql

Currently using VS2013,and what I am trying to do is to update the last entry on a table while a certain condition is true, however, my solution to this problem is not working properly since it crashes VShost. I decided maybe some experienced eyes would see the problem in a better way and help me out, the code is this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("A apagar dados...");
    bool check = true;
    do
    {
        string connectionString;
        var path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\connstring.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            connectionString = sr.ReadLine();
        }

        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string queryString = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection deleteconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            deleteconnection.Open();
            connection.Open();
            queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE numdoc = (SELECT MAX(numdoc) FROM WGCDOCCAB WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()),120))";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        using (SqlConnection deleteconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            deleteconnection.Open();

            queryString = "SELECT max(numdoc) FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())), 120))";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    check = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Dados Apagados com sucesso");
                }
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    while (check);
```

After the button is clicked, the connections is opened, the query runs and supposedly updates the entries on the table one by one as they meet the condition and then stops when its the condition is false, however the VShost keeps crashing and I have no idea how to fix this, as I said maybe some more experienced yes could help me and give me an explanation on how to work the problem.

EDIT: Thank you all for the help, i also stumbled upon this on the microsoft website, its a more efficient way to do it:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/111401

Again thank you for the help you all gave!

Comment: _"maybe some experienced eyes would see the problem"_  - that is not how debugging works. Place breakpoints, catch exceptions, find the problematic line.

Comment: I see the `do{` part but I don't see the `} while (condition);` ...

Comment: listen the experienced(codecaster) eyes :)

Comment: I tried using breakpoint without much sucess, i'm a fairly new programmer, that's why i was seeking help, will do the debugging more thoroughly, also edited the code, forgot the WHILE part sorry.

Comment: Why do you  keep reopening connections to the db? You keep opening 2

Comment: @bugfinder, i keep two connections because since im reading the connection string directly from a file it would give me syntax errors if i didn't have the code this way, maybe im screwing up doing that?Honestly i really don't know, i tried lots of things and read the MSDN documentation and nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem must be that your

```
queryString = "SELECT max(numdoc) FROM wgcdoccab ..."
```

Query will always have at least one row. Which will make `check` variable never set itself to `false` which causes your loop never to stop.
I think you don't need the `do{`  `} while (condtion);` and the `check` variable in your code at all.

Correct me on the `SELECT max(`... statement if I am wrong. I tried in SQL Server Manager and if no row met my condition, because of the `max(...)` function I still get a row containing `NULL`, without `max` function I get no rows in the result

I hope it helps you. Happy debugging!

Cheers!

Comment: I see, the problem is that i do need to know the max value therefore the statement, if i simply say that while the statement isn't NULL to keep updating, would it work? or maybe if i add something like
max(ISNULL(numdoc))

Comment: Maybe even `SELECT * FROM ...` is ok, but I am not sure this is the good way to approach the problem.

Comment: If i select * From the DB how will i know the max value of the numdoc ?
That is the problem wich started the whole thing, not sure what approachi should be taking on the problem

Comment: Your logic seems like, you get out of the loop when no result from the query, which made me think you are not interested in the max value, you are intersted if it has any records after deletion.

Comment: I want the loop to exit when the next max value (after updating) doesn't meet the conditions, do you understand? I know i am terrible at explainingso sorry.

Comment: I think the way to go would be analyzing what is your query returning in what cases. Instead of the condition `reader.HasRows` you will need something more clever there. Try manipulating that part

Comment: Well, i need a new algorithm, i'm gonna look into that, still thank you for your insightful comments, helps to have someone experienced to talk to.

Comment: The way your code is set up, `check` will never be set to false as `max()` will always return a result (a `null` row if nothing fits the criteria).  The question is, why are you doing the `SELECT` query after the `DELETE` at all.  Wrap the `DELETE` in a `try/catch` block and handle any errors, else display the success `MessageBox`

Answer (score 1):

As @DDan mentioned, the returning set from `max()` will always return something that has rows (a `NULL` row if nothing satisfies the criteria).  This means that `reader.HasRows` will always be true, thus `check` will never be `false` resulting in the endless loop issue.

However, looking at your code it seems what you're trying to do is:

- Delete a row from the database
- Ensure that it was deleted and display a "Deletion Successful" message box

If this is the case, then you don't need your second `using(SQLConnection deleteconnect...` block at all.

Wrap the execution of the `DELETE` command in a `Try/Catch` to handle any errors, and within the `try` block display the `MessageBox` after the execution.

However, if you really want to do a `SELECT` to ensure what was deleted was actually deleted, you'll need to do something like this:

Execute `Select max(numdoc) FROM wgcdoccab...` and save the result to a variable e.g. `recordToDelete`

Then run `DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE numdoc = @recordToDelete`

Then run `SELECT numdoc from wgcdoccab WHERE numdoc = @recordToDelete` and ensure you get 0 records.  From there you can show your Deletion Successful `MessageBox`